# Get BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead` when try to compile the react application

Tags: css, reactjs, compilation, package, isomorphic

I use in my project react template - [React Isomorphic Redux Admin Dashboard](https://themeforest.net/item/isomorphic-react-redux-admin-dashboard/20262330) 
Try to compile the react app with this template: 
 1. `npm install` `yarn install` 
 2. `npm run build dev` or `yarn run build`

and every time I get this error when use `yarn` for instance:

> yarn run v1.13.0
>       $ node build && node copy
>       Creating an optimized production build...
>       Failed to compile.
>       
>      ./node_modules/nprogress/nprogress.css  
>       Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead`
>       at Array.forEach ()

[BrowserslistError when try to compile the react app with `yarn`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvKOf.png)

When I use `npm` I get the same error, but with different `....css` file. 
Here img of error with `npm` 
[BrowserslistError when try to compile the react app with `npm`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2iun.png)

> isomorphic@2.9.3 build /Users/romank/code/instagram/public 
>   node build && node copy "dev"
>
> Creating an optimized production build...
>   Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/containers/App/global.css
>   Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead`
>       at Array.forEach ()
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
>   npm ERR! errno 1 
>   npm ERR! isomorphic@2.9.3 build: `node build && node copy "dev"`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the isomorphic@2.9.3 build script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/romank/.npm/_logs/2019-02-21T15_10_28_618Z-debug.log

Here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "isomorphic",
  "version": "2.9.3",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.6.5",
    "antd-local-icon": "^0.1.3",
    "auth0-lock": "^11.1.2",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "card-react": "^1.2.7",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "clone": "^2.1.1",
    "cp": "^0.2.0",
    "cp-cli": "^1.1.2",
    "cp-file": "^6.0.0",
    "cp-folder": "^1.0.8",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "d3-shape": "^1.0.6",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "enzyme-react-intl": "^1.4.8",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "firebase": "^5.2.0",
    "fixed-data-table-2": "^0.8.8",
    "frappe-charts": "^0.0.8",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.0",
    "globalize": "^1.2.3",
    "history": "^4.6.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "immutable-devtools": "^0.0.7",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "js-info-bubble": "git+https://github.com/RedQ/js-info-bubble.git",
    "js-rich-marker": "^1.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "polished": "^1.7.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-inline-rtl": "^0.9.8",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "raf": "3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.5.2",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.17.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.5.7",
    "react-codemirror": "^1.0.0",
    "react-count-down": "^1.1.0",
    "react-dates": "12.2.4",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dnd": "^2.3.0",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-drawer": "^1.2.5",
    "react-dropzone-component": "^3.0.0",
    "react-element-resize": "^0.2.1",
    "react-error-overlay": "1.0.6",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^2.0.0",
    "react-flip-move": "^2.9.2",
    "react-google-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "react-grid-layout": "^0.16.2",
    "react-instantsearch": "^4.0.7",
    "react-intl": "^2.3.0",
    "react-ladda": "^5.0.6",
    "react-motion-drawer": "^2.1.7",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.2.0",
    "react-placeholder": "^2.0.0",
    "react-quill": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.5",
    "react-sidebar": "^2.3.2",
    "react-smooth-scrollbar": "^8.0.6",
    "react-speech-recognition": "^1.0.4",
    "react-tag-input": "^4.7.2",
    "react-tags": "^0.2.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
    "react-throttle": "^0.3.0",
    "react-trend": "^1.2.3",
    "react-vis": "^1.7.2",
    "react-window-size-listener": "^1.0.10",
    "react-yandex-maps": "^2.3.0",
    "react-youtube": "^7.4.0",
    "recharts": "^1.0.0-alpha.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.2.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "redux-saga-firebase": "0.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.0",
    "rheostat": "^2.1.1",
    "rich-marker": "^0.0.1",
    "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.2.5",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "styled-components": "^2.2.1",
    "styled-theme": "^0.3.3",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "uppy": "^0.30.0",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.4",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3",
    "yandex-map-react": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.2.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.0",
    "google-maps-react": "^1.1.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.2.0",
    "leaflet-routing-machine": "^3.2.5",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.0.6",
    "mv": "^2.1.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "1.4.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.3",
    "webpack-php-loader": "^0.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node build && node copy"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "mjs",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

How can I fix this error? Did anyone face to this problem?

By the way, how do better run the `npm` and `yarn` commands with `sudo` or without?

Thank you.